# Ensure that fields with specific annotations are 'private'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-analysis, checkstyle, pmd

Very common mistake in our code is to write

```
@Mock Object object;
@InjectMocks Subject subject;
```

instead of

```
@Mock private Object object;
@InjectMocks private Subject subject;
```

This prevents PMD/FindBugs/IntelliJ from issuing warning when the field becomes unused and also our code reviews are bloated with "make this field private" comments.

Is there any static-analysis rule in any tool to warn when fields with specific annotations do not have expected visibility?

I found Checkstyle's [VisibilityModifier](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#VisibilityModifier), but it marks all non-private fields, not just the ones with specific annotations.

Comment: Won't post this as a new answer, because I don't have access to it - it's a commercial tool. Fortify seems to support both [structural](https://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2013/12/2/building-fortify-custom-rules-for-spring-mvc.html) and [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634663/writing-rules-in-fortify) queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the *Structural Search Inspection* in IntelliJ IDEA. For example with a pattern like this:

```
@Mock @Modifier("packageLocal") $FieldType$ $FieldName$ = $Init$;
```

FieldType: min: 1, max: 1
FieldName: min: 1, max: 1
Init: min: 0, max: 1

Comment: Thanks - do you think it is possible to automate it on Jenkins and to fail the build with meaningful message if such pattern is matched?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has an inspect.sh script it's bin directory, which can be used for something like this. You might also need some kind of plugin for Jenkins. Sorry I can't be more helpful, I have never used Jenkins myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PMD's Rule Designer to create a new XPath rule, which can be embedded into a PMD ruleset xml file. I haven't used PMD with IntelliJ IDEA or Jenkins, but I'm sure the plugins exist.

Here's a rule I've made (not tested outside the Rule Designer):

```
<rule  name="NonPrivateMockAnnotation"
  message="Mock anotation should be private"
  class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule">
  <description>
  </description>
  <properties>
    <property name="xpath">
    <value>
<![CDATA[
//ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration[
    Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name[
        @Image = 'InjectMocks' or
        @Image = 'Mock' 
    ] and
    FieldDeclaration/@Private = 'false'
]
]]>
    </value>
    </property>
  </properties>
  <priority>3</priority>
  <example>
<![CDATA[
class Example {
  @Mock Object object;
  @InjectMocks Subject subject;
}
]]>
  </example>
</rule>
```

Comment: And here's a tutorial on writing rules: http://techtraits.com/programming/2011/11/05/custom-pmd-rules-using-xpath/

Comment: Above link seems to be gone, adding an archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150522015043/http://techtraits.com/programming/2011/11/05/custom-pmd-rules-using-xpath/