# PMD exception BeanMembersShouldSerialize on Autowired fields

Tags: java, spring, autowired, pmd

I get PMD exceptions like "BeanMembersShouldSerialize" on autowired fields. The only way to stop them is using either "transient" or @SuppressWarnings. My question is what would be the right way to deal with PMD and autowired fields.

```
@Component
public class Sample {

@Autowired
private SoapProperties soapProperties;

public void doSomething() {
    // do something
}
```

Sample.java:13: Found non-transient, non-static member. Please mark as transient or provide accessors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are two options. Firstly, here's the [documentation for the check](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/pmd-java/rules/java/javabeans.html).

The first option is adding a supression to your rule via the properties: violationSuppressRegex, violationSuppressXPath, prefix. I havent used the Regex and XPath options, but the XPath is interesting - if you learn to write it, you can also implement completely new checks (the syntax and AST structure are a bit arcane though). For an example of how a supression looks like in your ruleset.xml, and maybe some more info [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331272/pmd-violationsuppressxpath-for-all-rest-get-methods).

The second option is taking the check's java code linked there, and implement the exception for autowired there, and then reference your class in the ruleset, while disabling the original `BeanMembersShouldSerialize` check. I think this would be harder, and more likely to require maintenance down the line.

Comment: This answer on writing new XPath checks might also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33977637/293115

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier answer - perhaps it didn't exist back in the day.  Just add "Autowired" to the list of ignoredAnnotations.  This worked for me in PMD 6.16.0

```
<rule ref="category/java/errorprone.xml/BeanMembersShouldSerialize" >
    <properties>
        <property name="ignoredAnnotations" value="lombok.Data|lombok.Getter|lombok.Value|Autowired" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks .. just fyi .. ignoredAnnotations property doesnt work anymore
Execution failed for task ':pmdMain'.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set non-existent property 'ignoredAnnotations' on Rule BeanMembersShouldSerialize

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: This may help: make sure your build.gradle is using the latest version of the PMD plugin. Here's how you can do that: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html#sec:pmd_configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify it a little differently,

```
<rule
    ref="category/java/errorprone.xml/BeanMembersShouldSerialize">
    <properties>
        <property name="ignoredAnnotations"
            value="lombok.Data|lombok.Getter|lombok.Value|org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```